# Problem with type plugin and custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, plugin-types

### Function

```
function get_taxonomy_names($post_id, $term_name) {
$collections = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $term_name, array("fields" => "all"));
$count       = count($collections);
$return = '';
if($count > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach($collections as $collection) {
        $return .= $collection->name;
        if($count > 1) {
            if($count == $i) {
                continue;
            }
            $return .= ', ';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
return $return;
```

}

### Product template

```
< $products_category = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'category-products'));?>


    <div class="sorting-block">
        <div class="content-xs">
            <ul class="sorting-nav sorting-nav-v1 text-center">
            <? foreach ( $products_category as $collection ): ?>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="category"><?=$collection->name;?></li>
            <?endforeach;?>    
            </ul>
        </div>


    <? $products = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 400,) ); ?>

    <? foreach ( $products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <? $pic               = types_render_field("product-pic", array("url"=>"true")); ?>
    <? $serial_number     = types_render_field("serial-number", array("url"=>"true")); ?> 

        <ul class="row sorting-grid">
            <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mix" data-cat="category">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?=$pic;?>" alt="">
                    <span class="sorting-cover">
                        <span><? the_title(); ?></span>
                        <p></p>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>     
        </ul>
    <?endforeach;?>
```

### Problem

I have product category which I did by types plugin 'custom taxonomies'. I want to show products by category when somebody clicks the category name that should show just that products which registered to for example "acril" category. Problem is when I am debugging products it is not showing category. So I should connect both foreach circle if you paid attention I have data-filter in circle 1 and data-cat in the second circle with value 'category'. that should be dynamic and what can be key for that connection if post not showing the any keys.

Comment: Please stop using those crappy short php tags. You should never use them, they are not recommended in WordPress and just poor coding habits IMHO

Comment: I know when I am rushing do that or that is just bad habit!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the category name as well if you want to show posts from specific category..

You just need to add one more param to the get_posts array.

REPLACE THIS

```
<? $products = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 400,) ); ?>
```

WIth THIS

```
<? $products = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'products',  'category_name' => 'category_name_here', 'posts_per_page' => 400,) ); ?>
```

Comment: in that gives me empty array